# Security issues while sending variable from Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, security, get

I'm developing JavaScript game. I need to insert some records (such as score, time, level, etc.) to database.

To do It I can use JavaScript in following:

```
function jsFunction() { 
  var jsScore = 1000;
  window.location.href = "file.php?score=" + jsScore; 
}
```

And in PHP file I could use `$_GET['score'];`

But looks like this way is not secure, user could change score at address bar directly in browser. Am I wrong?

How could I do It in more secure way?

Comment: Any information coming from the client can't be inherently trusted.  You'd have to be able to validate in server-side code that the value is acceptable.

Comment: @David thank you for your time. About server-side validation I heard before, but I have no ideas how It should be done. How could I validate for example score in server-side? Could you give me some tips?

Comment: Since it's a pretty broad question, I can only give a broad response.  But basically the server-side code should be tracking values that you don't want the user to be able to modify.  Client-side code can use those values for convenience, but the "source of truth" should be server-side.  So for example a "score" calculation should likely be done server-side.  The client-side code may send events to the server, and the server-side code returns the results of those events (such as the updated score).

Comment: @David thanks for an answer. So as I understand: I have table of actions in database. For example: `ActionId: 1; ActionName: BallTouchBasket; Score: 100` so in in client side when ball touch a basket I should insert ActionId instead of Score directly and from server-side I should select total score for that user? Something like that? How about completion time? It should every second update database table?

Comment: Potentially something quite a bit more granular than that, since the user could still spoof a bunch of actions that aren't actually being performed.  The server-side code would really be tracking the full state of the game environment, and the client-side application would just allow the user to do things in the game (move in a direction, use an item, etc.).  The server-side code would validate that the current known state of the user permits the action, updates the state of the user, and updates the state of the game environment.

Comment: @David Hmm, I'm confused now. If I have `var curretLevel = 1;` in JavaScript. User could change It to any level as he like. So if I make server-side validation in this way: Store all possible levels in database table and select current level after done some action. So from PHP file value of current level will be sent back to JavaScript and js file will be: `var currentLevel = lvlSentFromPHP`, so user could edit It such as `var currentLevel = 15;` huh...

Comment: Well, yes, the user can edit *locally*.  But when the user tries to perform another action on the server any invalid data being sent would be rejected.  The user would see himself as "level 15", but anybody else playing would see the server's data that the user is "level 1".  You can't stop the user from changing things in their browser, but you can stop them from changing things on your server.

Comment: @David in my case It's puzzle game. That higher level that more pieces. So logic for that is like: `var puzzleMatrix = currentLevel;`  somehow I need to pass value for `puzzleMatrix` to start the game. Logic of building puzzle pieces are wrote in JavaScript (client-side) so I need to provide size of matric in JavaScript too. That's mean I am on wrong way? So all logic of cutting puzzle into pieces  should be stored in database?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sending the data via AJAX post would be more appropriate. Technically the user could still edit it using the dev console but it much less visible.

```
<script>
function jsFunction() { 
  var jsScore = 1000;
  $.post( "file.php", { score: jsScore})
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: As you say, the user *can* still modify the values.  Easily.  Also, why the use of jQuery here?

Comment: Hi David, correct the user still edit the data by digging through the console, I was just stating this method would be less visible since it doesn't involve editing a url in the browser. 

And secondly that was out of habit, of course I should mention for the OP a jQuery include will be required for this. Certainly agree with your explanation regarding server side validation.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of the `jquery` library and send the ajax request to the php page. like below.

```
function jsFunction() { 
  var jsScore = 1000;
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "file.php",
    data: { score: jsScore }
  }).done(function(response){
     //you can perform some activity after score saved etc..
  }).fail(function(response){
     //you can perform some activity if score do not saved etc..
  })
}
```

then you can access the score using `$_POST['score'];` in php.

Comment: (1) Why the jQuery recommendation, what does that have to do with the question?  (2) You're not using the `jsScore` value.

Comment: hmm... first made ajax than surrounded it by function that's why. i will make change.

Comment: So what if user replace this `var jsScore = 1000;` with `var jsScore = 999999;`?

Comment: @Infinity I have given you example that how you can send the value to your server. As your question is it self consists of one whole secure system which can't directly answered. Their are also server side validations, SSL and what not which can help you to make sure that the data is not get altered in between.

Answer (score -2):

Try sending data in post using ajax. This will not show data in url and is also secure as the data passes in post.Here is the code

```
    var score = '1000';
    var time = '10';
    $.ajax({
            url: 'file.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {score: score, time: time,},
            success: function(posData) {
                // success code here
            },
        });
```

In file.php you can get all parameters in

```
print_R($_POST);
```

Comment: This is just as insecure as a GET request.  The values can be modified by the user just as easily.  Your assertions to the contrary are woefully incorrect.

Comment: Atleast this is secure than passing throug url where all can see and edit!!

Comment: You can also pass encoded data and check on server side with the key weather the data is correct or modified.

Comment: @rushil: And the user can see the code which is performing the "encoding" and "encode" their own values.  You aren't adding any security here.  Just because you may not know how to break this "security" doesn't mean it can't be broken.

Comment: Lets say i am using HS256 method for encryption and the key is passed from server in php vairable. so the encoding can be seen but the key is not visible. same things can be decoded on server side which is completely secure. Now truly speaking everything can be hacked and is not safe.

Comment: By the way there may be many safer options other than my anwser which i can not deny.